# How to create pages when 2 or more pages appear in printdocument

Tags: .net, printdocument

I have for loop here that creates a rectangle for every number I input in a `textbox`, it `creates 3 columns and 4 rows` in a page, my question is how can I add A new page in my `printdocument1` I have my sample here where in I set the count of box to 15 but it makes it 1 page and there is a minimum box in the lower part of the paper. I also try e.hasmorepages but it loops infinitely.

please see picture https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501936921061

and this is my codes below.

```
    Dim RectTemplate As New Rectangle(0, 0, 250, 250)
    Dim GapPx As Int32 = 12                  ' set gap between rectangles
    Dim StaPt As New Point(GapPx, GapPx * 2)   ' set starting point
    Dim N As Int32 = Val(TextBox1.Text)                  ' set (or get) the totalnumber of rectangles
    Dim nL As Int32 = Math.Floor((e.PageBounds.Width - GapPx) / (RectTemplate.Width + GapPx))  ' number of rectangles per row
    Dim nR As Int32 = Math.Ceiling(N / nL)   ' number of rows of rectangles 
    For ir = 0 To nR - 1       ' process all rows
        For il = 0 To nL - 1   ' process all rectangles in a row
            If (nR * RectTemplate.Height) > e.PageBounds.Height Then
                e.HasMorePages = False
            Else
                Dim rect As New Rectangle(StaPt.X + il * (RectTemplate.Width + GapPx), StaPt.Y + ir * (RectTemplate.Height + GapPx), RectTemplate.Width, RectTemplate.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Sienna, rect)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

any help is very much appreciated thanks in advance.